# Why does JSONObject.optString add garbage to my strings?

Tags: android, json

I am starting with the json:

```
{
    "Key1" : "Value1",
    "Key2" : "Value2"
}
```

I am then hard-coding this json in a string:

```
String json = "{ \"Key1\" : \"Value1\", \"Key2\" : \"Value2\" }";
```

Next I attempt to parse the json:

```
JSONObject content = null;
try {
    content = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}       

String key1 = content.optString("Key1", null);
```

If I look at the hashmap created from the call to JSONObject, it looks correct:

```
{Key2=Value2, Key1=Value1}
```

But when I look at the value of the string key1 in the debugger, I get this:

```
[V, a, l, u, e, 1, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U, U]
```

Where U appears to be unicode character 25A1 (White Square).

I've also tried the generic get("Key1") method, casting the result to a string and I get the same behavior?!?

Comment: What does the following return? `"Value1".equals(key1);`

Comment: Maybe I'm way off here but defining a JSON object like that seems painful with all the escape characters. Have you tried using myJsonObject.put(string key, object value) to see what is stored?

Comment: @Jack It is painful but it was just a simple hack to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ahh gotcha - Yes I have noticed that sometimes when debugging a bunch of garbage is appended to my strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see an issue with your code, as this slight modification appears to work:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String json = "{ \"Key1\" : \"Value1\", \"Key2\" : \"Value2\" }";

    JSONObject content = null;
    try
    {
        content = new JSONObject(json);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    String key1 = content.optString("Key1", null);
    System.out.print(key1 + "end!");
}
```

The console output says this:  `Value1end!`

When looking at the code in the debugger, I saw this:

[image]

If I were to venture a guess, it may just be additional buffer space the debugger is using to hold the `String`.  Have you tried seeing what your code thinks it is?

```
"Value1".equals(key1); //should return true if everything is working correctly.
```

Comment: My evaluation is also true.  Perhaps it is debugging garbage, I was concerned that once I parse a more complicated object that my arrays and sub-ojbects would become tainted.  I may have been too paranoid.

Comment: Sometimes it is best to just code it up and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

optString(java.lang.String key)      Get an optional string associated with a key.

you should use

getString(java.lang.String key)    Get the string associated with a key.

Or am i missing something?

For more: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html